# Get current wallpaper

Tags: android, methods, wallpaper

I'm pretty new to Android programming so bear with me.

I was wondering if there was a method of retrieving the current wallpaper on an android device and saving it to a variable in your app's code.

Thanks

Comment: None of the answers here helped, but the following answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53912364/647292.  It uses the WallpaperManager.getWallpaperFile method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

This solution is not valid for Android 13
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237124750?pli=1

Comment: What if a Live wallpaper is set ?

Comment: @S.D. In this case, I have no idea what will be returned, but you can call "getWallpaperInfo" in order to check if it's a live wallpaper : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperInfo()

Comment: @S.D. In this case, from what I see, the last set wallpaper will be returned.

Comment: Do you know whether this requires any permissions?

Comment: As of android version 8.1, WallpaperManager.getDrawable() will require READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, unfortunately this is not talked about in the official docs.

Comment: @QLocker exactly , but you will get SecurityException when you execute above snippet code and that SecurityException tell you to grant READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Answer (score 4):

This is the good way to do that:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes a step further and saves the file. You'll need exception handling of course and you'll need external write permission.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;

WallpaperManager wmInstance = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

wmInstance
    .getDrawable()
    .getBitmap()
    .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
        new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/output.png"))
```