# Android get wallpaper name

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

I am developing an Android app for our company which sets the wallpaper to a specific company wallpaper every time the phone is booted.  It would be preferable to check to see if the wallpaper has been changed rather than running the code to change the wallpaper.

Is there any way to get identifying information (e.g. filename etc.) from the current wallpaper?

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
WallpaperInfo wallpaperInfo = wallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo();
```

returns `null` for `wallpaperInfo`.

Code for wallpaper change:

```
public static void setWallpaper(Context context) {

    // Has wallpaper changed?
    if (/*--wallpaperNotChanged--*/) {
        return;
    }

    try {

        // Setup
        Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

        // Get display sizes
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        // Create Bitmap
        Bitmap unscaledWallpaper = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.test);
        Bitmap wallpaper = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unscaledWallpaper, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels, true);

        // Set wallpaper
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);

    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [get-current-wallpaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939329/get-current-wallpaper). And [Get current wallpaper absolute path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperInfo.html)

```
final Drawable wallpaperManager = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

For better info you can visit:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperInfo.html

Answer (score 0):

[WallpaperManager API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperInfo())

```
public WallpaperInfo getWallpaperInfo ()
```

Here it says:

> ***If*** the current wallpaper is a **live wallpaper component**, return the information about that wallpaper. Otherwise, **if it is a
>   static image**, simply return **null**.

You must be having a static image wallpaper in your background, not a live one.