# Show default phone wallpaper in ImageView

Tags: android

How to display users phone wallpaper to ImageView using Java in Android Studio?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9939358/5192105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Drawable wallpaper = WallpaperManager
            .getInstance(this)
            .getFastDrawable();
```

You can get it like this.